# Do I need to implement destructor for a C++ class not allocating resources?

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

I'm working on a concurrent programming exercise from my university textbook: I got to implement a custom concurrent buffer used by two threads (a consumer and a producer) where the consumer introduces a new value using some method (`next()`) and declares he's done enqueuing with `stop()`, while the consumer asks for the new value (calling `consume()` ) or waits if none in the buffer. In case one of the threads using the buffer faces an exception, it calls `fail()`. Here's my code (I'm not mentioning all the details of the requirements because they're not relevant for this question)

```
template <typename T>
class Buffer {
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::queue<T> values;
    bool stop, failed;
    std::exception_ptr _eptr;

public:
    Buffer() : stop(false), failed(false) {}

    void fail (const std::exception_ptr &eptr){
        std::unique_lock ul{m};
        failed = true;
        _eptr = eptr;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void terminate(){
        std::unique_lock ul {m};
        if (stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error("enqueing has stopped");
        stop = true;
        cv.notify_one(); // notify stop signal
    }

    void next(T t) {
        std::unique_lock ul{m};
        if ( stop || failed ) throw std::runtime_error ("enqueing has stopped");
        values.push(t);
        cv.notify_one(); // notify the consumer (if waiting)
    }

    std::optional<T> consume(){
        std::unique_lock ul{m};
        cv.wait(ul, [this]() { return !values.empty() || stop || failed; });
        if (values.empty()) { // if got notified and the queue is empty, then stop or failed have been sent
            if (stop)
                return std::nullopt;
            else
                std::rethrow_exception(_eptr);
        }
        // extract the value to consume
        T val = values.front();
        values.pop();
        return std::optional<T>(val);
    }
};
```

I'm wondering if I need to also implement the destructor to guarantee the proper life cycle of this object or if the default one is enough because all the objects I'm using are indeed destroyed/released by their own constructors. If it is the case, can you please suggest what the destructor should contain ?

EDIT:
I guess the program using it might look like this

```
    Buffer<int> buf;

    std::thread prod([&buf](){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; ++i) {
            std::cout << "enqueing: " << i << std::endl;
            buf.next(i);
        }

        buf.terminate();
    });

    std::thread cons([&buf](){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
            std::cout << "consuming: " << buf.consume().value() << std::endl;
    });

    prod.join();
    cons.join();
```

Comment: if you are inheriting this class, you will need a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: Your implementation is a bit confusing. How can you possibly use `terminate` safely? If you need it, it's because there might be a thread calling `next` or `consume`. But then how will you know when it's safe to call the destructor? Is the user expected to call `terminate` and then use their own code to synchronize prior to invoking the destructor? Maybe `join`ing all threads that might be using the container?

Comment: Classes are not concurrent, threads (and processes) are. So, you probably mean instances of this class are used concurrently. In any case, you can abuse them, but if used and implemented correctly, there are no additional requirements due to concurrency. To be honest, this makes this Q very open-ended and unsuitable for SO, but it would be much better in codereview.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz as I said, this is a programming exercise then I just followed the specifications. The requirement was to have a method `terminate` the producer calls to stop enqueuing. I think the general idea is to have two threads working on this object and then to joining them. Sorry if my question is a bit misleading

Comment: read about [the rule of 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Classes that manage a resource should do only that, all others can follow the rule of 0

Comment: I just edited the question. Hope it's now clearer. I'm a student then please forgive me for my mistakes, all of this is intended for didactic purposes

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number then, according to that, I don't need the destructor because the default one is called at the end of the life cycle of my object and so the cv, the mutex and so on are destroyed by their own destructors ? What if nobody calls `terminate` though ? Is that a problem ?

Comment: if some thread is calling `consume` which blocks and a different thread calls the destructor on the same object then you have a problem. Also in your example, the consumer expects to be notified exactly 10000 times, but what if (for whatever reason) `cv.wait(..` only returns after the producer added two or more values and notified already twice. However, thats a bigger design issue, not only about the destructor

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the code in the "EDIT" part is just a quick example I wrote based on my understanding of the problem. I mean, the buffer might be used in several other ways. Tbf it's like a blocking queue. Anyway, ignoring for a moment the design part, do you think the destructor is actually needed ?

Comment: boils down to: Does `Buffer` manage a resource. When it needs to notify others waiting to be notified before its lifetime ends, then that is a kind of "resource". On the other hand, as already mentioned it should never happen that another thread is calling `consume` while the `Buffer` gets destroyed, because then you are in trouble anyhow

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number would calling `terminate` inside the destructor solve the problem ?

Comment: the lifetime of the object ends when the destructor call starts, hence one thread waiting in `consume` while the other calls the destructor is a problem you cannot solve in the destructor